# How to improve the performance of the Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, select

I have a Mysql Query:

```
select stu_photo, type, sign, type1, fname,regno1 
from stadm 
where regno1 = XXXXXX 
LIMIT 1000;
```

stadm table has 67063 rows. Execution time period of above query is 5-6Mints.
am unable to add index for stu_photo and sign column (there datatype is blob & longblob) Table_Enginee is Innodb. How can i increasing the performance (i.e., To reduce the execution time period)?

Answer (score 0):

One improvement I can see for your query would be to add an index on the `regno1` column.  This would potentially speed up the `WHERE` clause.

> am unable to add index for stu_photo and sign column

These columns should not impact the performance of the query you showed us.

Another factor influencing the performance of the query is the time it takes to send the result set back to your console or application.  If each record be very large, then things may appear slow, even for only 1000 records.

Answer (score 0):

create a new column md5_regno1 from type varchar and store the md5 from regno1 in it. then you can create a index on the new column search like this:

```
select stu_photo, type, sign, type1, fname,regno1 
from stadm 
where md5_regno1 = MD%('XXXXXX') 
LIMIT 1000;
```